# Character encoding issue for httpost between android app and spring rest service

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, http-post, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to make my android app talk with my spring REST web service. I am making `httpost` from android as below code. However I am getting the exception below. whatever I set for `content type` of my post request it did not work. if there is not non-english character in my post object, it works well. However if there there is şŞüÜöÖgG etc. it gives that error. I need your advice.

```
public SowHttpUtil executeConnection(Object obj) throws Exception {
    try{
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
        if(obj != null){
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(objToString(obj));
            se.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("application/json");
            httppost.setEntity(se);
        }
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        //httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset="+HTTP.UTF_8);
        //httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        //httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset="+HTTP.UTF_8);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
            responseString = convertStreamToString(inStream);
        }else{
            Log.e("RESPONSE STATUS ERROR : " , "RSCode : "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            throw new SowException(R.string.error4);            
        }
    } catch(HttpHostConnectException e){
        throw new SowException(R.string.error4); 
    }
    return this;
}
```

The exception I am getting at server side (spring):

```
Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@79e0123b; line: 3, column: 29]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@79e0123b; line: 3, column: 29] 
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@79e0123b; line: 3, column: 29]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@79e0123b; line: 3, column: 29]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@79e0123b; line: 3, column: 29]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidInitial(Utf8StreamParser.java:2825)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidChar(Utf8StreamParser.java:2819)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString2(Utf8StreamParser.java:1978)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString(Utf8StreamParser.java:1905)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.getText(Utf8StreamParser.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:13)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:184)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
new StringEntity(content, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

instead.

The constructor for `StringEntity` calls `getBytes()` on the supplied string with the charset (check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1-beta2/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.java#StringEntity.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29)). If no charset is provided, then the default one is used (and it's not UTF-8).

Calling `setContentEncoding()` afterwards changes the HTTP header, but *not the content itself*. Hence the mismatch (`0xfc` is not valid UTF-8)

Comment: it was kind of deep detail. didn't know that. thanks for your working answer.

Comment: HTTP.UTF_8 shows up as deprecated now, any ideas what replaced it?

Comment: @Neth `HTTP.UTF_8` is now deprecated, but so is `StringEntity`, along with the full Apache HTTP client package. :)